# many positions to fill?

Tags: headlinese

[image: many positions to fill !!]

I saw this ad, which I feel like is not good English.

How does it sound to a native speaker? is it ok to say "many positions to fill" or is there another way to say it?

Comment: Looks fine to me. This is [tag:headlinese], which doesn't require full sentences.

Comment: Thank you, as you see , it is a google translate to the same words in French.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the (largely, non-existent) grammar of "headlinese".

Comment: better English means better world. I don't think closing the reason to close the question is enough. no harm  there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, "headline English" has its own kind of grammar where many of the standard rules are not enforced.  For example:

> Sixth Sheikh's Sixth Sheep Sick, Shames Shepherd

Naturally, creative people who write these headlines can have a lot of fun.

In this case there's really nothing *wrong* with "Many positions to fill".  It's perhaps not as *artful* as it could be, and sounds like a direct translation from the French, but perhaps that's deliberate to make it more appealing?  As a Canadian company located in Quebec, I suspect they're looking for people fluent in both languages, so it's also possible they consider the English translation to be a redundant *courtesy*.